Error Canceling Job
I was trying to resize the files in one of my HDD but decided to cancel it but it keeps on giving me an Error
"Error Canceling job; The job has already been cancelled (udisks-error-quark,2)". I don't have much important stuff on it but I would like to be able to use the info on it.

I would probably not have cancelled a resize, as the worst condition I'd want is a disk in an unknown or inconsistent state.. but you've provided few specifics.  What Ubuntu product/release are you using? what file-system was involved? Have you tried flushing buffers (sync etc) on your system? or did you wait for it to complete? or have you rebooted etc?

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, The gnome-disks application, I have not flushed buffers yet but I did rebooted. I was waiting for it to finish but it was going on for about 2 hours.
